# C-SERVER - strange behaviour at: strncpy(ii2, iii + 5, 3);

Tags: c

Let's send a message to C-SERVER:

```
echo '1234567890' | nc <ip> <port>
```

C-SERVER prints: ( **oo.ooo.o** = partial IP of client )

```
678oo.ooo.o---
```

But I only asked it to print **3 characters** from the incoming message.
( starting from **5th** character )

```
strncpy(ii2, iii + 5, 3);
```

it should only be printing: ( plus the **---** )

```
 678
```

**Question:** WHY is it attaching a partial IP address of the client to the string above ?

**EXTRA INFO:**

The problem seems to go away when I remove this line all together:

```
snprintf(iip, 15, "%s", inet_ntoa(cli_addr.sin_addr));
```

But I do not want to remove that line.

**FULL CODE:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <string.h>

char * nnn;
char iii [500];
char ii2 [3];
char iip [15];


int main()
{
  int one = 1, client_fd;
  struct sockaddr_in svr_addr, cli_addr;
  socklen_t sin_len = sizeof(cli_addr);

  int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (sock < 0)
    err(1, "can't open socket");

  setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &one, sizeof(int));

  int port = 86;
  svr_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  svr_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  svr_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

  if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &svr_addr, sizeof(svr_addr)) == -1) {
    close(sock);
    err(1, "Can't bind");
  }

  listen(sock, 5);
  while (1) {
    client_fd = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &sin_len);
    snprintf(iip, 15, "%s", inet_ntoa(cli_addr.sin_addr));
    ssize_t t = read(client_fd,iii,500);

    if ( t > 0 ) { iii[ t ] = '\0'; ii2[ t ] = '\0'; }

    strncpy(ii2, iii + 5, 3);

    printf(ii2);
    printf("---");
    printf("\n");
    asprintf(&nnn, "%s\n", ii2);


    write(client_fd, nnn, strlen(nnn));
    close(client_fd);
  }
}
```

Comment: You forget the string terminator needed when you copy to `ii2`.

Comment: @Some programmer dude, can you tell me how it can be done ? I am not good with C (yet).

Comment: First of all, for a string of three characters you need an array of *four* characters because of the terminator. Secondly, `strncpy` might not add a terminator so you have to do it explicitly (like e.g. `ii2[3] = '\0'`). Unrelated to your problem, stop using global variables, and please try to come up with some *descriptive* variable names. Learning good habits early will help you later.

Comment: I'm not sure what the point of `ii2` is, but it almost certainly should be a local variable. However, if the only reason is to print 3 characters starting with the sixth character of `iii`, the variable and the copy are unnecessary: `printf("%.3s", iii+5);` will do just that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to increase `char iip [15];` size to 16. Its common issue for beginers to forgot preserve room for `'\0'` character. `char ii2 [3];` is also too short to store string with the length of 3, so I suggest to increase the room to 4.

Comment: `ii2` is also too short and misused (`strncpy` does not make it a C string).

Answer (score 4):

You are using `strncpy` incorrectly. This function is designed for use with fixed-length strings - something that is rarely used these days.

The function copies three characters into `ii2`, but it does not add a null terminator. Replace the call with a call to `memcpy`, and set `'\0'` in the last character, like this:

```
char ii2 [4]; // <<== 3 plus 1 for '\0'
...
memcpy(ii2, iii + 5, 3);
ii2[3] = '\0';
```

Note that if all you need is to print three characters from a possibly longer string, you do not need `ii2`. You can use `%.3s` format specifier, like this:

```
asprintf(&nnn, "%.3s\n", iii+5);
```

You need to call `free(nnn)` to avoid creating a memory leak. In addition, since the size of the result is limited to 5, you can replace `asprintf` call with `sprintf` to a buffer of fixed size.

Comment: @chqrlie Thank you for the comment!

Answer (score 2):

Adding to [dasblinkenlight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42327826/1783971)'s answer.

```
char ii2 [3];

ssize_t t = read(client_fd,iii,500);

if ( t > 0 ) { iii[ t ] = '\0'; ii2[ t ] = '\0'; }
```

This looks like a recipe for `SegFault`. Trying to store value at a location which is well beyond the `ii2` array size. (Worst case: t = 500)